# How to use OutputPath across multiple components in kubeflow

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

We are defining multiple components in kubeflow pipelines using `@dsl.containerop`.

There are two steps involved in the requirement.

1. First we need to run a download task, which takes an input `url` and download the file inside the container.
2. We need to use the file which got generated in the first step and run a python program -this will be done in the seconds containerop.

Sample code is as below.

```
@dsl.component
    def download(url: str, output_file: OutputPath(str)):
        return dsl.ContainerOp(
            name='Download',
            image='busybox:latest',
            command=["sh", "-c"],
            arguments=["wget %s " % url, output_file)],
        )
```

And the above mentioned code will be invoked using

```
download_task = download(url=<URL>")
```

As per the component spec https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/reference/component-spec/ - the output path doesnt needs to be mentioned.

https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/d106a6533bf4e1cbda4364560bc7526cb67d4eb2/samples/tutorials/Data%20passing%20in%20python%20components/Data%20passing%20in%20python%20components%20-%20Files.py#L69 - `@func_to_container_op` - We could see a way to get the output using OutputPath type.

Is there any way to achieve this in `dsl.containerop`. We dont want to hardcode the output path using `file_outputs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in ContainerOp, that was one of the reasons ContainerOp has been deprecated, refer to https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/pull/4166.

Suggestions:

1. Following https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/reference/component-spec/ to build your reusable component yaml.
2. if you prefer inlining component yaml for one-off components, you can load it via `kfp.components.load_component_from_text` method refer to [this example pipeline](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/f757a8842fd6d1ed3d37ab38c0707d127ea2048c/samples/core/output_a_directory/output_a_directory.py#L49).

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. 

In our usecase, we have two steps. 

1. First step downloads the data into some specific path
2. Second step we need to use the downloaded data and train.

Most of the kubeflow example talks about the data passing as strings. My assumption is , if we have multiple component.yaml, we can generate the output in first step and use the same variable in the second one. 

Do you have any suggestions to pass folder path across multiple components (running in different containers)

Comment: Passing files/folders across containers is already supported, refer to this section of above doc: https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/reference/component-spec/#consuming-input-by-file

Comment: @srinath KFP does not quite "pass paths" - the paths are container-local. KFP passes actual data (files, directories) - KFP takes the output data from the upstream component container and then puts it in downstream component containers.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following two tutorials for [shell](https://github.com/Ark-kun/kfp_samples/blob/master/2019-10%20Kubeflow%20summit/106%20-%20Creating%20components%20from%20command-line%20programs/106%20-%20Creating%20components%20from%20command-line%20programs.ipynb) and [Python](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/samples/tutorials/Data%20passing%20in%20python%20components.ipynb).

Here is how you can write a downloader component:
(Save this as `component.yaml`) and then do `download_op = load_component_from_file('component.yaml')`

```yaml
name: Download data
inputs:
- {name: Url, type: URI}
options given to the curl bprogram. See https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html'}
outputs:
- {name: Data}
implementation:
  container:
    image: curlimages/curl
    command:
    - sh
    - -exc
    - |
      url="$0"
      output_path="$1"
      mkdir -p "$(dirname "$output_path")"
      curl --get "$url" --output "$output_path"
    - inputValue: Url
    - outputPath: Data
```

There is also an example of a pipeline that downloads data using `curl` and then trains on that data: [XGBoost pipeline](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/2909f259c46257c0db7614cdc7e1cd7329ca6f6b/components/XGBoost/_samples/sample_pipeline.py)

P.S. There already exists a component to download data from web:
`download_op = load_component_from_url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeflow/pipelines/master/components/web/Download/component.yaml')`

Comment: In the shell script you have a line `output_path="$1"`. How do we pass the output path argument?

Comment: You can see the whole command line in the `command` array. The `$0` comes from `{inputValue: Url}`. The `$1` comes from `{outputPath: Data}`. You cannot set output paths (or input paths) explicitly, but you don't need to. The paths are local to a hermetic container and do not affect the outside world. Do you really care whether the output path is `/tmp/outputs/Data/data` or `/foo/bar/baz`? Each component runs separately. They are on different machines, disks. The component just needs to read from the provided input paths and write to the provided output paths and the system will do its work.